# Python Broken on linux

Tags: python

First time asking a question so please excuse any problems with the posting.

I can't seem to get any python script to execute properly, commands are not functioning. Running a script that only contains a `print` statement:

```
print "Hello World"
```

results in:

> Error: no such file "Hello World"

Running python and typing commands into the shell works fine.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: How exactly do you run the scripts? Include a complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty certain you're *not* using Python to run your code. From my `bash` shell:

```
pax$ print "Hello World"
Error: no such file "Hello World"
```

That pretty much shows that it's `bash` executing your code, not Python. The easiest way to check this is to run it by giving it as an argument to the Python interpreter directly:

```
pax$ python myscript.py
Hello World
```

Once you've established that fixes your issue, you just need to add a shebang line to the top of your Python script so the `bash`, if it does try to run it, will pass it off to the *correct* program for it. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Hello World" # use parentheses in Python 3
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response! Can't believe I missed such a basic step.... Its been about a year since I've done python but still, Really embarrassed.

Comment: Don't be embarrased, @Hime0698, I do silly stuff all the time. I'll never *tell* you about it though :-)

Comment: Note that this is syntax for Python 2, get used to the idea that you'll have to switch to print("Hello world")

Comment: @Anon, question was for Python 2, as print with parentheses would have given a different error in bash. But I'll add that to answer, cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You can install ipython on your Linux distro. Its an amazing tool to get started with Python.

You can see a sample python print command executed in ipython.

```
Air:~$ ipython
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: print ("Hello World")
Hello World
```

To install ipython on Ubuntu, just execute the below command.

```
sudo apt-get install ipython
```

Thanks!